# Chart.js displaying the text in center of the doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, tailwind-css, react-chartjs

I was trying to add implement the idea of placing text inside the pie chart and it doesn`t work as expected

```
import React,{useEffect, useState,useMemo} from 'react'
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip } from 'chart.js';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';



ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip);

export default function Roundedstats() {


  const [input1,setInput1] = useState(0);
  const [input2,setInput2] = useState(0);
  const [inputd1,setInputd1]=useState(0);
  const [inputd2,setInputd2]=useState(0);
  const [inputd3,setInputd3]=useState(0);
  const [inputd4,setInputd4]=useState(0);
  const [count, setCount] = useState([0,0,0]);
  const targetValue = useMemo(() => [input1, inputd1, inputd3], [input1, inputd1, inputd3]);


   useEffect(()=>{ 
    const inputValue=70;
    const inputValue1=30;
    const inputValue2=60;
    setInput1(inputValue);
    setInput2(100 - inputValue);
    setInputd1(inputValue1);
    setInputd2(100-inputValue1);
    setInputd3(inputValue2);
    setInputd4(100-inputValue2);
    
    const durations = [5000,5000,5000];
    const increment = targetValue.map((value, index) =>
    Math.ceil(value / durations[index] * 10)
  );

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setCount((prevCounts) =>
      prevCounts.map((count, index) =>
        count < targetValue[index] ? count + increment[index] : count
      )
    );
  }, 10);

  return()=>clearTimeout(timeout)   


   },[count,targetValue]);


    const data={
        datasets:[{
          data:[input1,input2],
          backgroundColor: ['red','#071952'],
        }]
      };

      const data1={
        datasets:[{
         data:[inputd1,inputd2],
         backgroundColor:['#0BB230','#071952']
        }]
      };

      const data2={
        datasets:[{
          data:[inputd3,inputd4],
          backgroundColor:['#F87700','#071952']
        }]
      };

      const options={
        responsive:true,
        cutout:'80%',
        layout:{
          padding:20,
        },
        borderWidth:'',
        plugins: {
          beforeDraw: (chart) => {
            const ctx = chart.ctx;
            const xCoor = chart.chartArea.left + (chart.chartArea.right - chart.chartArea.left) / 2;
            const yCoor = chart.chartArea.top + (chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top) / 2;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = 'bolder 24px';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
            ctx.fillText(`${input1}`, xCoor, yCoor);
            ctx.restore();
          },
        },
      };

  return (
      {/* Stat 1 */}
       <div className='flex flex-col px-2 pb-2 overflow-hidden border-2 border-black rounded-lg gap-y-4'>
        <Doughnut data={data} options={options} op />
        <h1 className='text-xl font-extrabold text-center font-Inter'>No of Visitors</h1>
       </div>
      {/* Stat 2 */}
       <div className='flex flex-col px-2 pb-2 overflow-hidden border-2 border-black rounded-lg gap-y-4'>
        <Doughnut data={data1} options={options}/>
        <h1 className='text-xl font-extrabold text-center font-Inter'>No of Forms</h1>
       </div>
      {/* Stat 3 */}
      <div className='flex flex-col px-2 pb-2 overflow-hidden border-2 border-black rounded-lg gap-y-4'>
        <Doughnut data={data2} options={options}/>
        <h1 className='text-xl font-extrabold text-center font-Inter'>No of Contracts made</h1>
       </div>
  )
}
```

I have Tried all the options to implement this idea but it is not displaying in the center, I didn`t find where the error has been occurred , Please help me with the solution to resolve the error .Spot me where the workflows stops and the error was done by me

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your custom plugin in the wrong place of chart configuration.

It should:

1. remove plugins from options if your plugin doesn't need any config
2. add plugin implementation to plugins filed of Doughnut tag(component)

Code

```
  const options = {
    responsive:true,
    cutout:'80%',
    layout:{
      padding:20,
    },
    borderWidth:'',
    plugins: {
    },
  };
  const myPlugin = {
      id: 'myPlugin',
      beforeDraw: (chart) => {
        const ctx = chart.ctx;
        const xCoor = chart.chartArea.left + (chart.chartArea.right - chart.chartArea.left) / 2;
        const yCoor = chart.chartArea.top + (chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top) / 2;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.font = 'bolder 24px';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText(`${input1}`, xCoor, yCoor);
        ctx.restore();
      },
  }
  ........
   
  <Doughnut data={data} options={options} plugins:{[myPlugin]} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your grateful help mate ! Is there any other font customizations to make bigger  because when I change the 24px it is not changing and doesn't give the desired result

Comment: Canvas context 2d is using font representation like CSS one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font Ahving a look to you code, it seems the family is missing.

Comment: Maybe the best thing is to use Chart.js helper for font. Chartjs.helpers.toFont() which is returning an object which has got a property, "string" which is the correct one for the canvas context 2D.

Answer (score 0):

this will work
const textCenter = {
id: "textCenter",
beforeDatasetsDraw(chart: any, args: any, pluginOptions: any) {
const { ctx } = chart;
ctx.save();
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText(
highestValue + "%",
chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x,
chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y
);
},
};
<Doughnut data={data} options={options as any} plugins={[textCenter]} />